# How to set a complete wheel filename?

Tags: python, python-wheel, hatch

I'm looking for to create a wheel filname with complete wheel filename as I can see on Pypi wheel files of many projects and avoid to use setup.cfg or other tools as it is describe at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Actually I'm using the *build* package and the *build-backend* Hatch to generate my wheel file (pyprojectfile.toml).

I wish to obtain a shape wheel filename as {dist}-{version}(-{build})?-{python.version}-{os_platform}.whl, i.e for my project, cleanmysurface-0.0.3-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl

```
with my build command :

python -m build

I obtain a wheel filename ***cleanmysurface-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl***

As I understand the effecting mapping is :

name --> cleanmysurface
version --> 0.0.3
build --> py3
python.version --> none
os_platform} --> any

**but** I want to obtain :

name --> cleanmysurface
version --> 0.0.3
build --> py310
python.version --> py310
os_platform --> macosx_10_9_x86_64

Are my metadata correct ? Do I need an another tool to create this wheel (Poetry, Flit, ...) ?

pyproject.toml :

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "cleanmysurface"
version = "0.0.3"
authors = [
{ name="blabla", email="blabla@icloud.com" },
]
description = "A melange package to calculate your mixture to clean surfaces"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
platform = "macosx_10_9_x86_64"

classifiers = [
"Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
"License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
"Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/blabla/melange"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/blabla/melange/issues"
```